# Convert tuple to dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a tuple as follows:

```
(1, ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

How can I convert such tuple into the following dictionary?

```
{1: ['a', 'b', 'c’]}`
```

My actual tuple look like this:

```
a = (0, ['http://www.armslist.com/posts/2997703/pittsburgh-pennsylvania-handguns-for-sale--80--1911-frame', 'http://www.armslist.com/posts/4240186/racine-wisconsin-rifles-for-sale--stainless-winchester-m70-300wsm'])
```

When I am trying to convert it to a dictionary using `dict(a)` it is giving an error:

> TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence

How can I resolve it?

Comment: How is that a dictionary? Dictionary is a key:value pair, that looks more like set.

Comment: sorry for the typo. {1 : [‘a’,’b’,’c']}

Comment: `dict([my_tuple])` will give you the dictionary you seek

Answer (score 2):

You could pass an iterable of tuples to a `dict`:

```
In [22]: dict([(1,['a','b','c'])])
Out[22]: {1: ['a', 'b', 'c']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dict([a])`

```
In[56]: a=(0, ['http://www.armslist.com/posts/2997703/pittsburgh-pennsylvania-handguns-for-sale--80--1911-frame', 'http://www.armslist.com/posts/4240186/racine-wisconsin-rifles-for-sale--stainless-winchester-m70-300wsm'])
In[57]: dict([a])
Out[57]: 
{0: ['http://www.armslist.com/posts/2997703/pittsburgh-pennsylvania-handguns-for-sale--80--1911-frame',
  'http://www.armslist.com/posts/4240186/racine-wisconsin-rifles-for-sale--stainless-winchester-m70-300wsm']}
```